# Send PDF to the browser rather than saving to the server - ASP.NET iText 7 C# Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, webforms, itext7

this is my first time posting on SO

I have been using iText 7 so users of my web app can generate a pdf of a document.

I would like the document sent to the browser so either it gets saved to the user Downloads folder or the user can choose where to save it with the browser save dialog box.

However, all the C# examples I have found require a hard-coded path & file name, so it gets saved on the server rather than client machines.

I have been researching this for a few days now and floundering around with solutions, this is what I have:

```
public void mtdCreatePDF()
{
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=print.pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
var stream = new MemoryStream();
var writer = new PdfWriter(stream);
var pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
var document = new Document(pdf);

document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello world!"));
document.Close();

Response.Write(document);
Response.End();

}
```

This creates print.pdf in browser Downloads folder, but the file is corrupt.

I would be grateful if someone could point out where I am going wrong, the majority of articles in this regard relate to the older itextsharp, and the iText 7 examples have hard-coded file paths and file names.

I have found one possible solution that looks good, but unfortunately it is in Java. I've been floundering around for ages trying to convert it to C#, but I don't know any Java so it's turned into a pig's breakfast. This is the Java solution:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(baos));
Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
doc.add(new Paragraph("Hello world!"));
doc.close();

// setting some response headers
response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control",
"must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
// setting the content type
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
// the contentlength
response.setContentLength(baos.size());
// write ByteArrayOutputStream to the ServletOutputStream
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
baos.writeTo(os);
os.flush();
os.close();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: i'm not a C# programmer, but shouldn't you be using BinaryWrite instead of Write on your response?

Comment: You try to write a `Document` instance (`Response.Write(document)`). But the iText document only offers a facade to access PDF reading and writing functionality, your code actually creates the document in the `MemoryStream stream`. Thus, you should write its contents (something like `Response.Write(stream.ToArray())`). (I'm not into .Net web service creation APIs, so details might have to be corrected.)

Comment: @AndréLemos this is a Frequently Asked Question on Stack Overflow. Maybe we need more code examples where we don't use files?

Comment: At my work, we ended up finding a free component for this purpose, we've been using this one for years to both create the pdf, and output it to the browser: http://www.asppdf.com/ I know that isn't exactly an answer to the question but it might be a different possible direction to consider.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I have used both your suggestions: Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray()) It seems to be working perfectly. I shall post the completed code to assist others with the same issue. Thank you for your help, I have spent days trying to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: @erastl  I'll have a look at that asppdf - it looks interesting an might provide a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

This solution seems to be working perfectly.

```
public void mtdCreatePDF()
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=print.pdf");
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            var writer = new PdfWriter(stream);
            var pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
            var document = new Document(pdf);
            document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello world!"));
            document.Close();
            Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
            Response.End();
        }
```